# How to make such a CV in LaTeX?

Tags: moderncv, document-classes, cv

I am not good to LaTeX. I think I need TikZ? It should look like [this](http://www.ausbildungspark.com/files/gegenchronologischer-lebenslauf-beispiel.png):

[image]

Can anyone help me? How to do that? Which document class should be used, how to make the sectioning look like that on the photo, how to place the title, how to place the picture and the box over it and so on. I don't know how to make it. Can anyone help me please?

Here my beginning on the problem:

```
%http://be-jo.net/2012/05/lebenslauf-mit-latex-mustervorlage/
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Name}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Straße}{Stadt}
\mobile{Mobiltelefonnummer}
\phone{Telefonnummer}
\email{Emil}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Persönliche Angaben}
\cventry{Geburt}{Datum}{Stadt}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use any class.  I'd use `article`, I guess, along with the `graphicx`, `xcolor`, and `geometry` packages, and probably `xparse`.  The rest could be set up with `minipage` and `tabular` environments.  That would be enough to get started on the project, anyway.

Comment: [europecv](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/europecv/europecv.pdf) is a style that is somewhat similar.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  If you can, could you give a full example of how to use `europecv`?  As it stands, this is more of a comment than a full answer.

Comment: @ Basilius Sapientia: If you actually worked out a solution it'd be nice if you could share your solution with us, thanks.

Comment: [komacv](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/komacv)

Comment: http://www.texdev.net/index.php?s=curriculum

Comment: @ChrisS To be fair, it is the question so it is not altogether beyond the pale for it not to be an answer to that question. (Although I admit that it would reduce the number of unanswered questions on the site if questions had to meet this criterion!)

Comment: Please at least provide a basic document structure with dummy content so that people don't have to construct something from scratch, which is especially a pain when you have to keep switching between a graphic display and source code for guidance.

Comment: @cfr all right. I have made a minimal example :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is probably not exactly what did you want (because you are asking for LaTeX solution and I give TeX solution) but I hope that this answer illustrates the **typical usage of TeX**. There are two persons: macro programmer who implements the macros by given typography design and the author who writes the text. The programmer tells to the author what markup is needed to use.

First, what writes the author:

```
\input cv-mac 

\title   {Lebenslauf}   
\name    {Selman Caragöz}   
\address {Henkestraße 2\nl 60412 Frankfurt / Main}
\tel     {069 170 06 85}
\mobile  {0177 96 24 56}
\email   {s.caragoez@web.de}
\photo   {photo.png}
\print

\sec Persönliche Daten

\bb Geburstdatum:        = 25.06.1993 in Antalya / Türkei
\bb Staatsangehorigkeit: = deutch
\bb Familienstand:       = ledig
\bb Beruchfiles Ziel:    = Hotelfachmann
\bigskip

\sec Berufstätigkeit

\bb seit 01.2013         = Hotel Zur Post, Frankfurt\nl
                           Mitarbaiter im Frühstucksservice\nl  
                           Vorberaitung des Buffets, 
                           Eindecken und Abräumen der Tische,
                           Anrichten von Speisen
\bb 09.2012--12.2012     = Restaurant Am Wasserturm, Franfurt\nl
                           Servicemitarbeiter (befristet)\nl
                           Gastebedienung, Abrechnung

\sec Berufsfachshule

\bb 08.2011 -- 07.2012   = Städtische Schule Frankfurt-Ost\nl
                           Einjährige Berufsfachshule Gastronomie\nl
                           Berufsbezogener Unterricht: Service, Küche, Magazin\nl
                           4-wöchiges Praktikum in der Küche und am Empfang
                           im Ibis-Hotel, Frankfurt,\nl
                           Bestandene Abschlussprüfung

\sec Auslandsaufenthalt

\bb 08.2010 -- 06.2011   = Aufenthalt in der Türkei\nl
                           Mithilfe im Obst- und Gemüsehandel des Onkels
                           (Lager, Verkauf)

\sec Schulausbildung

\bb 08.2014 -- 07.2010   = Otto-Hanh-Schule, Frnkfurt\nl
                           Qualifizierender Hauptschullabschluss

\bb 08.2000 -- 07.2004   = Gemeinschaftsgrundschule Hermesgasse, Frankfurt

\bb 08.1999 -- 06.2000   = Grundschule in Antalya, Türkei

\sec Zusatzqualifikationen

\bb Führerschein         = Klasse B

\bb Sprachen             = Türkisch (Muttersprache), Englisch (gute Schulkenntnisse)

\bigskip

Frankfurt / Main, 03.07.2013

\signature{sig.png}

\bye
```

Second, what prepares the macro programmer (the file `cv-mac.tex`):

```
% cv-mac  
\nopagenumbers % use pdfcsplain
\input chelvet % Helvetica fonts

\font\bfont=\fontname\tenbf\space at12.5pt
\font\hfont=\fontname\tenbf\space at17pt
\font\sfont=\fontname\tenrm\space at9pt

\hoffset=-1in \voffset=-1in
\pdfpagewidth=210mm \pdfpageheight=297mm

\hsize=\pdfpagewidth \vsize=\pdfpageheight
\def\bcolor{\pdfliteral{0 1 1 .6 k}}
\def\black{\pdfliteral{0 g}}
\def\white{\pdfliteral{1 g}}

\def\print{
  \line{\hfil\bcolor\vrule height 35mm width 45mm \black\kern\indentC}
  \nointerlineskip\vskip-25mm
  \line{\kern\indentA {\hfont \the\title}\hfil
     \white\vbox{\hsize=45mm \leftskip=2mm \baselineskip=11pt \noindent
        \bfont \the\name \nl
        \sfont \the\address \nl
        Tel: \the\tel \nl
        Mobil: \the\mobile \nl
        E-Mail: \the\email
  }\black\kern\indentC}
  \nointerlineskip \vskip8mm
  \line{\hfil\vtop to0pt{\image{43mm}{\the\photo}\vss}\kern\indentC}
  \vskip-5mm
}
\def\indentA{25mm}
\def\indentB{40mm}
\def\indentC{15mm}

\def\sec#1\par{%
   \vskip7mm
   \dimen0=\indentA \advance\dimen0 by\indentB
   \moveleft.5mm % optical correction
   \hbox{\rlap{\bcolor \vrule height4mm depth1.3mm width\dimen0}%
         \kern\indentA\kern.5mm\white#1\black}
   \vskip2mm
}
\def\bb#1 = {\par
   \noindent \hbox to\indentB{#1\hfil}%
   \hangindent=\indentB
}
\parskip=3mm \parindent=0pt \leftskip=\indentA

\def\image#1#2{\pdfximage width #1{#2}\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}

\def\newtokss#1{\ifx\relax#1\else \csname newtoks\endcsname #1\expandafter\newtokss\fi}
\newtokss \title \name \address \tel \mobile \email \photo \relax

\def\nl{\hfil\break}
\def\signature#1{\par\hbox{\kern\indentA\image{50mm}{#1}}}
```

Third, what is the result:

[image: cv]

If you can try this, use `pdfcsplain cv.tex` command. You can use `pdftex cv.tex` too but this second command doesn't work right with UTF-8 characters like ß or ü. Of course, you need to prepare the `photo.png` and `sig.png` images before TeX processing.

Note that you needn't any special LaTeX packages. The pure pdfTeX is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! But is TeX included in the TeXLive package? I made two files (one named cv-mac.tex) and run the "author" file. But I just get a lot of errors like. "! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \nopagenumbers". What do I do wrong? I use TeXMaker and PDFLaTeX and then run the script.

Comment: Of course, TeX, pdfTeX and pdfcsplain are included in the TeXLive package :). If you get the error Undefined `\nopagenumbers` then you are not running pdfTeX nor pdfcsplain but LaTeX. The command at the command line has to be: `pdfcsplain cv.tex` no `pdflatex cv.tex`. And the files `photo.png` and `sig.png` have to be prepared.

Comment: Wow, that window manager with xpdf remember me my first Linux in 1995  `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The CV design has to do with a lot of things. In part are style conventions, in many places (maybe in all the World) is required to CV occupies only one page, if you exceed, most likely not even read it and end up in the trash.

There are also subtle differences that exist in Europe and America (to name two examples) such as the paper size, the disposition on the page of the different parts of the curriculum, typographical conventions, and more that in this moment I haven't entirely clear and that surely someone else can answer in another subsequent answer.

You can find in sites like [LaTeXTemplates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae) examples of classes or templates for create your on CV with different layouts that can be helpful for you. Although... in fact I don't know if you can get exactly the same layout from your link, but there are many examples that can give you an idea. If not maybe you must to improve your LaTeX and Tikz skills and make your own, but meanwhile take a look at those examples, you can download them or open in the cloud with [WriteLatex](https://www.writelatex.com/templates) or maybe find them in [ShareLaTeX](https://es.sharelatex.com/templates).

Comment: CVs in academia are typically several pages at least in North America and the UK, and I think Europe more generally.

Comment: That's right, but outside academia and for young people should be as short as you can.

Comment: For young people outside academia, perhaps. But then the general statement is false. (Since LaTeX is disproportionately used in academia, ignoring this is rather misleading.)

Comment: @cfr Uhm... good point.

Comment: @Aradnix: So maybe you will want to incorporate this into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

An example you might want to use: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter. Adapt to your needs, if you encounter any problems you can always come back here for help. You could also try to use parts of these other templates: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae

For document class it uses {moderncv} with options 11pt, a4paper, sans. Title placement will be taken care of by the class, the photoframe comes from \photo[picture height][frame thickness]{picture}. Just take a look at the template, it is really good and explains about everything that is done.